# Can you solve this (very hard) integral?

Tags: integration

$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(|x|^2+i\varepsilon)(|x-a|^2+i\varepsilon)(|x-b|^2+i\varepsilon)(|x-c|^2+i\varepsilon)} dx^4 \\
=f(|a|,|b|,|c|,|a-b|,|a-c|,|b-c|) $$

The solution to this integral is the (symmetric) function $f$ of 6 variables. Can you find this function? $\varepsilon$ is a small number which indicates which way around the pole we go.

$a,b,c,x$ are all 4-vectors $(\in \mathbb{R}^4)$.

I have a feeling that the solution may involve the volume of a tetrahedron in some way since the points $a,b,c$ and the origin make 4 corners of a tetrahedron but that is purely a guess.

Perhaps it may be solved as a power series in terms of the variables of $f$. (By symmetry $f$ will be a symmetric function).

I'm not even sure how to start. I tried converting to polar coordinates but this didn't help.

I feel like there's some sort of residue theorem I should use but not sure what it is. I believe it satisifies (for each variable):

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}f = \frac{1}{|a|^2 |a-b|^2 |a-c|^2}$$

if that helps.

Comment: How are $|a-b|$ and the others important?

Comment: @Integrand. Because the integral is rotationally and translationally symmetric, the only independent variables are the distances between the points O,a,b,c. So these are the distances between these points. One point is set at the origin to make it slightly simpler.

Comment: @Joel Yes, the  variable is integrated over. so $f$ doesn't depend on $x$. $f$ is the result of the integral.

Comment: @zooby Sorry, I had misread your expression.